# Rake - halt on Rails migrate errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

Is there a way to make rake halt execution when invoking the Rails migration tasks?  Right now it  runs straight through attempting each one.  What I really want is to attempt drop, then attempt create, and if either of those are successful, then run migrate, then seed if that is successful, stop and display an error if any failures.

I've tried invoke on each task, testing the result but, that doesn't seem to be right either.

Thanks.

```
task :fresh_start => [
  'db:drop',
  'db:create',
  'db:migrate',
  'db:seed'] do
end
```

Answer (score 1):

By default Rake will stop at the first exception raised. For instance the following will never print "That".

```
task :this do
  puts "This"
  raise "Fail!"
end

task :that do
  puts "That"
end

task :default => [:this,:that]
```

Isn't that what you'd like ?

Comment: That would be ideal.  I'm calling Rails migrate tasks and they don't seem to throw exceptions internally.

Comment: I think what I'm really looking for are known returns from the Rails tasks:   Say Rake::Task['db:drop'].invoke.   For example, if db:drop returns failure or success or some other status code.